# FF browser is opened but throwing error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner to Selenium and I am using Selenium 3.14, java 8, geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.

Firefox browser is opened successfully though i am getting below error messages.

```
1550013525709   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Ram\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.qTo8ZZnL5enA"
1550013526312   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1550013526313   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1550013528547   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 49687
1550013528917   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Feb 12, 2019 3:18:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Successfully opened the website
1550013531218   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 49687
[Parent 420, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 3900, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 3900, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe errorJavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/WebProgressChild.jsm, line 58: TypeError: this.mm.content is null
[Child 5376, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 5376, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build[Parent 420, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 5532, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
```

My code:

```
package SamplePackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebdriverDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\Demo\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is doing everything you asked it to, so I'm not really sure what your question is.  `driver.close();` is probably not the function you are looking for.  Instead, try `driver.quit();`

Answer (score 1):

The drivers are often noisy, i.e. they write a lot to the logs. At first glance it might look like an error is being reported, it isn't really.

Although the logging says "pipe error" it is reported as a Warning:

```
WARNING: pipe error:
```

It is the "WARNING:" that you want to pay attention to, if that said "ERROR:" then you would be seeing errors.

Generally, if your code executes without an exception being thrown you are fine. If you experience an exception then have a look at the logs to see what is reported.